# Is there a vocabulary for linking machine data on the shopfloor?

Tags: data-request, linked-data, ontology, json

I've got a gateway that reads machine data on the shopfloor, e.g.

- running hours
- notifications ("low oil pressure",...)
- temperatures inside machine

The gateway should publish this data in JSON-LD.

For the context file I'm looking for a vocubulary to express the machine data. Is there already a vocabulary or 'setup' for this kind of data?

Are there sample immplementations for this domain?

Comment: try going through http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/vocabs

Comment: The typical place to start, I think, would be Schema.org. If the terms are missing, perhaps you can consider contributing them?